# ghost db-column in rails. undefined method `email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-activerecord

I have a strange error if I try to create a new model-object. The strange thing is that the column in the error message is not available in the database.
This is what I did:

My console-output:

```
1.9.3p286 :002 > person = OZBPerson.new
     => #<OZBPerson Mnr: nil, UeberPnr: nil, Passwort: nil, PWAendDatum: nil, Antragsdatum: nil, Aufnahmedatum: nil, Austrittsdatum: nil, Schulungsdatum: nil, Gesperrt: 0, SachPnr: nil, encrypted_password: "$2a$10$...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3p286 :003 > person.valid?
    NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<OZBPerson:0x007ffd2b30dee8>
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
```

My rails model:

```
class OZBPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "ozbperson"
    self.primary_key = :Mnr

    attr_accessible :Mnr, 
    :UeberPnr
end
```

My db-table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ozbperson` (
`Mnr` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`UeberPnr` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`Passwort` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
`PWAendDatum` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Antragsdatum` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Aufnahmedatum` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Austrittsdatum` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Schulungsdatum` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Gesperrt` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`SachPnr` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`encrypted_password` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '$2a$10$...',
`reset_password_token` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
`reset_password_sent_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`remember_created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`sign_in_count` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`current_sign_in_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
```

There is no such field like "email", but I still get this error message. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is because you are using devise. Devise's requires an email field so methods like its  reset_password_token (where attempts to find users by their email) can work. If you are not using devise ignore this answer, otherwise you'll need to add email to your person.

Comment: Yep, you are right, it is Devise's fault. I have now recovered the email-column.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using devise, add this to your model

```
def email_required?
    false
end
```

It overrides what currently exists in the devise model which is true.

Comment: Good point on this, you've got my upvote. I should have suggested it as well! I just figured that if he is using devise he probably wanted to take advantage of its confirmable/recoverable/etc features.

Comment: I think you can only have it one way or the other - either have email field be the unique identifier and use confirmable/recoverable/etc, or remove the email unique identifier and lose the ability to use confirmable/recoverable/etc.

Comment: That's what I meant :) I didn't list the email_required? option because I don't know why you'd add such a large library as devise if you didn't want to use all the features that require an email.

Comment: I actually just did this same thing last night for a project. Basically i have users that add other users to the app. They wanted to be able to add kids which don't have email addresses so i had to add this same code so that way it wouldn't bomb out on not having an email address. That was my use case anyways. I already had devise in and it does all the authentication stuff for me. It was the easy solution.